# Kendo ui window disable z-index changing on focus

Tags: kendo-ui

```
Please help!
```

I have function that create few windows. I set z-index for every window. But when some window got focus, it`s z-index change! How can i disable this feature? !!!!!

```
function createwindow(obj,objtype,x,y) {
        var jsobj = obj;
        v_obj[obj_count] = obj;
        obj_count = obj_count + 1;
        var wnd = $("#" + obj);
        wnd.kendoWindow({
            width: "150px",
            height: "150px",
            minWidth: "30px",
            minHeight: "2px",
            draggable: true,
            dragend: SaveWinAttrs,
            dragstart: onDragStart

        });
        $("#" + obj).parent().find(".k-window-action").css("visibility", "hidden");
        if (objtype == 'wh') {
      $("#" + obj).parent().find(".k-window-titlebar").css('backgroundColor','#fe2712');
                $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css('height', '100px');
                $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css('width', '100px');
                $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css('z-index', '11000');
        }

        $('.k-window-titlebar').css('height', '2px');
        $("#" + obj).parent().find("k-window-content,.k-content").css("padding", "0");
        $("#" + obj).parent().find(".k-header").css('min-height', '2px');
        $("#" + obj).parent().find(".k-header").css('height', '2px');
        //$("#" + obj).closest(".k-window").css({ top: x, left: y }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I create windows objects and array

```
var winArray = [];
 var winObject = new Object();
        winObject.nr = obj;
        winObject.color = $("#" + obj).parent().find(".k-window-titlebar").css("backgroundColor");
        winObject.x = $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css("left");
        winObject.y = $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css("top");
        winObject.h = $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css("height");
        winObject.w = $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css("width");
        winObject.z = $("#" + obj).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css("z-index");
        winArray.push(winObject);
```

Than on Drag end event restore z-index saved to object.

```
function onDragEnd(e) {
        if (winArray.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < winArray.length; i++) {
                $("#" + winArray[i].nr).closest(".k-widget.k-window").css('z-index', winArray[i].z);
            }
        }

    }
```